# How Child Themes Directory works for plugins?

Tags: child-theme

I am working on a Wordpress installation, that another developer used to do. I have an issue since he was working only with Child Theme Directory whereas I didn't.

What I want to do, is to edit the source code of a plugin. I read the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) but I am not sure if there is something there about it.

Will I just copy paste the file in the child directory and edit it or I must mention somewhere that I have edited this file and it should load it from the child directory?

The child directory has already created with many files, previously from the other dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plugins are not kept in the theme directory. It doesn't matter if you are using a child theme or not. Maybe you're asking a different question? Are you asking how to make a "child-plugin"?

Plugins are generally kept here: wp-content/plugins.

Whereas child themes and themes are kept here: wp-content/themes

As far as "child-plugins" there is not an official way to do it, but I think this article sums up pretty nicely what you could do to accomplish that, https://iandunn.name/the-right-way-to-customize-a-wordpress-plugin/ .

Comment: Maybe I am confused since there is a folder on the child theme directory from a Plugin folder. I will check your link and see what I could find

Comment: Ya, that's just bad practice. I recommend using this instead to accomplish your goal. http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-create-a-functionality-plugin/#.VcejYxNVhBc (offshoot of the previous link I gave you)